# Yum repo preference?

Tags: rpm, yum

Let's say we have two yum repos, red-repo and green-repo, which both contain *foo-bar-1.0.0.0.rpm*

The question is, if I run `yum install 'foo-bar-1.0.0.0'`, can I determine beforehand which repo yum will pull *foo-bar-1.0.0.0.rpm* from? More broadly, is there a setting/file where you can tell yum which repo to prefer if they both repos have the same file?

Comment: This would probably get better answers on https://superuser.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

From `man dnf.conf`:

```
cost   integer

The  relative cost of accessing this repository, defaulting to 1000. This value is compared when the priorities of two reposito‐
ries are the same. The repository with the lowest cost is picked. It is useful to make the library prefer  on-disk  repositories
to remote ones.

priority
        integer

The priority value of this repository, default is 99. If there is more than one candidate package for  a  particular  operation,
the  one from a repo with the lowest priority value is picked, possibly despite being less convenient otherwise (e.g. by being a
lower version).
```

These settings are old and are available for YUM too.